# Is Symfony looks for a service?

Tags: symfony

I am trying to do LDAP authentication, I currently have this type of error :

> ServiceNotFoundException: The service
>   "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a
>   non-existent service "form.csrf_provider".

Any help please ?

Comment: What version of symfony are you using? Post the contents of your `security.yml`

Comment: i 'am using SF V2.0.9

Comment: 2.0.9? Are you sure? But why? That it's a 4 years old release

Comment: the application which i use now is built on SF V2.0.9 so i think that i don't use  "security.csrf.token_manager"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [enable](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/framework.html#csrf-protection) `csrf_protection` in your configuration. Open `config.yml` and be sure that

```
framework:
    csrf_protection: true
```

is present in your configuration.

Comment: Well seen @Federico !

Answer (score 3):

The `form.csrf_provider` is deprecated and removed in Symfony 3.

Use `security.csrf.token_manager` instead.

My guess is that you are using a bundle that is not ready for symfony3.
Look at the README of your required bundles and to be sure they are compatibile.

See the  [3.0 CHANGELOG](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md) for all deprecated features.

**Update**

It's the inverse. You are on a too old symfony version, which doesn't support the `form.csrf_provider`, and you are surely using a bundle that require it.

Look for adapt your requirements or your symfony version.

**NOTE:** You should really change your symfony version for a stable release.

Comment: i still using SF V2.0.9 !